# Why is this for loop infinitely looping?

Tags: javascript

This for loop isn't working. When I enter:

```
console.log(children.length)
```

I get 4.

But when I look at the Developer Console, it shows a loop that doesn't terminate but also only seems to produce empty lines.

```
var curr_ans_code = 0;
for (var z = 0; z < children.length; z++) {
  if (z = curr_ans_code) {
    score += 10;
  }
  console.log(children[z]);
}
```

I feel I am missing something extremely basic, but can't figure out for the life of me what it is.

Comment: You want `==` not `=` in your `if`.

Answer (score 4):

You're setting z to be cur_ans_code (`z = curr_ans_code`), rather than testing its equality `z == curr_ans_code`.

Try this!

```
var curr_ans_code = 0;
for (var z = 0; z < children.length; z++) {
  if (z == curr_ans_code) {
    score += 10;
  }
  console.log(children[z]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (z = curr_ans_code) {
    score += 10;
 }
```

to:

```
if (z == curr_ans_code) {
    score += 10;
}
```

You're using assignment expression `=`, instead of equality `==`